# Count every distinct values from mongodb then render to amcharts

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack, amcharts

I'm trying to get the count of every distinct values from my mongodb, So far I can get the distinct values and count it.

**How can I do this:**

```
City       Count
Pasig       22
Manila      12
Pasay       11
```

**Sample document:**

```
_id:5c1ca770385b472018874073
blood_product_donated:"Whole Blood"
branch:"Pasay"
deferral_type:"none"
deferral_date:"none"
```

So far here is what I did:

**api.js**

```
router.get('/blooddonationpie', function(req, res) {
      Blooddonation.distinct('branch',function(err, branch) {      
      res.json({ success: true, branch: branch });
      console.log(branch);
   });   
});
```

**controller**

```
angular.module('blooddonationControllers', [])
.controller('blooddonationCtrl', function(Blooddonation,$scope) {
var app = this;
function getChart() {

    Blooddonation.getChart().then(function(data) {
        app.branch = data.data.branch; 
        initChart();      
    });
}
function initChart() {
    var data_series = [];

    for(let key in app.branch) {
        data_series.push({
            "donor": app.branch[key],
            "count": 501.9
        });
    }

    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
        "type": "pie",
        "theme": "none",
        "dataProvider": data_series,
        "valueField": "count",
        "titleField": "donor",
        "balloon":{
            "fixedPosition":true
        },
        "export": {
            "enabled": true
        }
    });
}
```

**This is the wrong output:**

**[image: This is the output:]**

How can I get the count for each distinct values? Example Pasig: 21, Pasay: 22 etc.

Comment: Please post sample documents and expected output?

Comment: please check again my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `$group` aggregation to get the count of each branches

```
db.col.aggregate([{$group: {_id : "$branch" , count :{$sum:1}}}])
```